# WebPy Sessions with Templates

Tags: session, web.py

Using Webpy. I have the following code in my app.py:

```
app = web.application(urls, globals())
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer={'count': 0, 'username': 'CRC'})
render = web.template.render('templates/', base="base", globals={'context': session, 'username': 'CRC'})

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):

        if not session:
                session.count = 0
        else:
                session.count = 1

        return render.hello_form()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(name="Nobody", greet="Hello")
        greeting = "%s, %s" % (form.greet, form.name)
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)
```

And then the following in my index html file:

```
$def with (greeting)

<p>
Hi <b>$context.username</b>
</p>
$if greeting:
        I just wanted to say <em style="color: green; font-size: 2em;">$greeting</em>.
$else:
        I just wanted to say <em style="color: green; font-size: 2em;">Default</em>.

<p>
<a href="/hello">Link Back To Form</a>
```

I'm seeing this once I submit the form:
 at /hello
'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'username'

Python  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/web/session.py in **getattr**, line 64
Web POST /hello

Any thoughts on why I am seeing this? It obviously doesn't like what I am doing with username, but it's not clear to me why.

Answer (score -1):

As the error says, the `context` variable (which is actually mapped to `session`), has no attribute `username`. Instead, you've defined `username` as a global var itself.

Try accessing `username` directly in your template as `$username`, or make the assignment `session['username'] = 'CRC'` in app.py, so that `$context.username` is valid when you access it in the template file.

Comment: Unfortunately not. 

initializer={'count': 0, 'username': 'CRC'}

should be setting $context.username in the template. There should be no need to set the username variable out side of the session being assigned to the variable context. I'm not sure why you are trying to do that. That said, I'm not sure why you are seeing an error, I am seeing the same one in a very similar situation.