# webpy template with session - ThreadedDict error

Tags: python, web.py

I have just started using web.py and am going through the documentation.  I'm trying to use session information in a template and have followed the instructions here http://webpy.org/cookbook/session_in_template however I get the an error ending with the following:

> AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'username'
>
> 127.0.0.1:53865 - - [14/Jan/2015 22:55:44] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 500 Internal Server Error

The code I'm trying to use is from this example: http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/sessions

I have included what I have below:

bin/login.py

```
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'Index',
    '/login', 'Login',
    '/logout', 'Logout'
)

web.config.debug = False
app = web.application(urls, locals())
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'))

class Index:
    def GET(self):
        if session.get('logged_in', False):
            render = web.template.render('templates', globals={'context': session})
            return render.logout()
        return '<h1>You are not logged in</h1><a href="/login">Login now</a>'

class Login:
    def GET(self):
        session.logged_in = True
        raise web.seeother('/')

class Logout:
    def GET(self):
        session.logged_in = False
        raise web.seeother('/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

templates/logout.html

```
<html>
<body>
<span>You are logged in as <b>$context.username</b></span>
<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried setting `session['username'] = 'CRC'` in the globals as suggested in [WebPy Sessions with Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906963/webpy-sessions-with-templates) but I get the same problem.

Can anyone see what's going wrong here?

Thanks,

Ger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured this one out.  Sessions.username doesn't exist by default and needs to be defined.  I used the initializer to set it.

```
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer={'username': 'test_user'})
```